# How to implement adaptive structure matching of imported xlsx files in Golang

Tags: excel, go, excelize

I have a requirement, it needs to `import xlsx file` to `bulk insert` objects into database.
Now, I am able to insert via pseudocode like below

```
import (
    "github.com/xuri/excelize/v2"
)
file, _, err := c.Request.FormFile("file")
if err != nil {
    return
}
xlsx, err := excelize.OpenReader(f)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
defer func() {
    if err := xlsx.Close(); err != nil {
        log.L(c).Info(err.Error())
    }
}()
rows, err := xlsx.GetRows(xlsx.GetSheetName(xlsx.GetActiveSheetIndex()))
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return nil, err
}
type TestObj struct{
    Test0 string   gorm:"column:test0" // Required fields
    Test1 string   gorm:"column:test1" // Required fields
    Test2 string   gorm:"column:test2" // Optional
    Test3 string   gorm:"column:test3" // Optional
    Test4 string   gorm:"column:test4" // Optional
}
objs := []TestObj{}
for i, row := range rows {
    if i == 0{     // 
        continue
    }
    var data TestObj
    for k, colCell := range row {
        if k==0{
            data.Test0=colCell 
        }
        if k==1{
            data.Test1=colCell 
        }
        if k==2{
            data.Test2=colCell 
        }
        if k==3{
            data.Test3=colCell 
        }
        if k==4{
            data.Test4=colCell 
        }
    }
    objs= append(objs, data)
}

service.BatchInsert(c,objs)
```

The way of `the above code` limits the **flexibility** of inserting data, for example, there are three options for Test2, Test3, and Test4.
Some uploaded forms may **only contain some optional attributes**. For example, the excel file contains `Test1, Test0, Test4, and Test3`, an error occurs when reading.

Is there some way to code that supports multiple upload file formats, such as Test0、Test1,Test4,Test3, and Test1,Test0,Test2, etc.

I really appreciate any help with this.

Comment: Never worked with that library and I don't really understand what you mean with "error on reading" b/c you're actually attempting to write, but did you try to make the optional fields pointers? Many libraries are build with support for those in mind.

Comment: Do you mean using option pattern? I think what is most needed is how to determine the `correspondence between each column and the fields in the struct`

Comment: I mean optional, like `test3` being of type `*string` instead of `string`. Btw. keep in mind you need to uppercase you field names in case `BatchInsert` shall be able to read them.

Comment: Thanks, I have modified the fields to capitalize the names. The `TestObj` is a table using the database corresponding to the `gorm`. At this time, do you need to use the `pointer` for optional items?

Comment: As I said, I've never worked with the excelize library. But in my experience many libraries with similar functionality honor the value `nil` and handle it differently than an empty/default value. That said, with your edits I get the impression that your problem is not reading from the excel file converting it to database item and but writing into a database with `gorm`. Is that correct?

Comment: My problem is reading from an excel file which is converted into a database item. The key is the `order of the columns versus the order of the struct fields`. With my reading code above, in order to write `Test0, Test1, Test4` data, I had to create **five** columns of data in the excel file, of which `test2, test3` are **placeholders** to ensure one-to-one correspondence.  But I don't like to do that, **I want to be able to match directly by three columns**

Comment: You shouldn't rely on the order of the fields in the struct. If it's about mapping those, you could create some custom tags telling about the corresponding cell number and evaluate those later, but that's feels like over-engineering. If you just want to get rid of all the `if` clauses, use `switch`. Without really heavy, potentially error-prone code (like reflection or tags) you won't be able to achieve a more generalized mapping. Alternatively, you can skip the ORM (gorm) and use something like sqlx, where you can insert a `slice` of arguments (in the desired order!) instead of an object.